Disconnect box to panel connection
Is it o.k to use a standard box to box connector at the lower knock-outs to attach an outdoor disconnect box to an outdoor sub-panel ? I've been told the is o.k since both boxes have manufactured knock-outs so they are not intended to be sealed in that area.

Yes, but a bit ironic an inspector will expect rain tight fittings.

similar question

Yes, That's my fear. I can't seem to find a water tight connector and I don't have space for two water tight hubs.
